# Is there a way to do iPhone recording with device output sound?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio-recording, recording

I am testing audio recording in iPhone with below code (audiotoolbox),
but while recording, I can't hear iPhone device's sounds.

Is there any way to do iPhone recording with device's sounds(it is not important like "using kernel patch" if possible)?

Should I use another API?

```
#include <AudioToolbox/AudioQueue.h>
#include <AudioToolbox/AudioFile.h>
#include <AudioToolbox/AudioConverter.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

#define AUDIO_BUFFERS 3

typedef struct AQCallbackStruct
{
    AudioStreamBasicDescription mDataFormat;
    AudioQueueRef queue;
    AudioQueueBufferRef mBuffers[AUDIO_BUFFERS];
    AudioFileID outputFile;
    unsigned long frameSize;
    long long recPtr;
    int run;
} AQCallbackStruct;

static void AQInputCallback(
                            void                                 *aqr,
                            AudioQueueRef                        inQ,
                            AudioQueueBufferRef                  inQB,
                            const AudioTimeStamp                 *timestamp,
                            unsigned long                        frameSize,
                            const AudioStreamPacketDescription   *mDataFormat)
{
    AQCallbackStruct *aqc = (AQCallbackStruct *) aqr;

    /* Write data to file */
    if (AudioFileWritePackets (aqc->outputFile, false, inQB->mAudioDataByteSize,
                               mDataFormat, aqc->recPtr, &frameSize, inQB->mAudioData) == noErr)
    {
        aqc->recPtr += frameSize;
    }

    /* Don't re-queue the sound buffers if we're supposed to stop recording */
    if (!aqc->run)
        return;

    AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer (aqc->queue, inQB, 0, NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    AQCallbackStruct aqc;
    AudioFileTypeID fileFormat;
    CFURLRef filename;
    struct timeval tv;
    int i;

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Syntax: %s [filename.aif] [seconds]", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    aqc.mDataFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;//kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    aqc.mDataFormat.mSampleRate = 44100.0;
    aqc.mDataFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
    aqc.mDataFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
    aqc.mDataFormat.mBytesPerPacket =
    aqc.mDataFormat.mBytesPerFrame =
    aqc.mDataFormat.mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof (short int);
    aqc.mDataFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    aqc.mDataFormat.mFormatFlags =
    kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsBigEndian
    | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger
    | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;
    aqc.frameSize = 735;

    AudioQueueNewInput (&aqc.mDataFormat, AQInputCallback, &aqc, NULL,
                        kCFRunLoopCommonModes, 0, &aqc.queue);

    /* Create output file */

    fileFormat = kAudioFileAIFFType;//.caf kAudioFileAIFFType;
    filename = CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation (NULL, (const UInt8*)argv[1], strlen (argv[1]), false);

    AudioFileCreateWithURL (
                            filename,
                            fileFormat,
                            &aqc.mDataFormat,
                            kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,
                            &aqc.outputFile
                            );

    /* Initialize the recording buffers */

    for (i=0; i<AUDIO_BUFFERS; i++) {
        AudioQueueAllocateBuffer (aqc.queue, aqc.frameSize, &aqc.mBuffers[i]);
        AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer (aqc.queue, aqc.mBuffers[i], 0, NULL);
    }

    aqc.recPtr = 0;
    aqc.run = 1;

    AudioQueueStart (aqc.queue, NULL);

    /* Hang around for a while while the recording takes place */

    tv.tv_sec = atof(argv[2]);
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    /* Shut down recording */

    AudioQueueStop (aqc.queue, true);
    aqc.run = 0;

    AudioQueueDispose (aqc.queue, true);
    AudioFileClose (aqc.outputFile);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that you the audio you send to the output can't be heard while you are recording?
If so, check that the volume isn't just very soft.
When recording from the mic, by default, the iphone will reroute output from the main speaker to the headset, to prevent feedback, since the speaker is right next to the mic.  This headset speaker is much softer, since it is meant to be used with your head up against it.  Try plugging in a headphone to check.
You can override this with the AudioSession API (which apple's documentation actually is okay for).